# How to retrieve data from relational database in Django

Tags: django, orm, model, relational-database

this Child_detail model is related to clinical_test model

```
class Child_detail(models.Model):
    Firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Tribe = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Religion = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    Current_Address = models.CharField(max_length = 50)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.Firstname
```

this is the clinical_test model by which i want to retrieve data from

```
class Clinical_test(models.Model):
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child_detail, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    Test_type = MultiSelectField(max_length=100,choices=test_type,max_choices=30)
    Test_date = models.DateTimeField()
    Next_schedule_test_date = models.DateField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Test_type)
```

this is my views.py

```
def more_about_child(request,pk):
    child = get_object_or_404(Child_detail,pk=pk)
    context={
        'child':child,        
    }
    return render(request,'functionality/more.html',context)
```

Here is my template.html by which will be used to show data that retrieved

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:rgb(44, 44, 3);color:white">
        <h4>clinical test</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>First name: <b>{{clinical.child.Test_date}}</b> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Last name: <b>{{child.Lastname}}</b> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Tribe: <b>{{child.Tribe}}</b> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Religion: <b>{{child.Religion}}</b> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Religion: <b>{{child.Date_of_birth}}</b> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Religion: <b>{{child.Current_Address}}</b> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step by step solution- (as far as I understand what you need)

1. First query the child from the Child detail class using pk

   child_detail = Child_detail.objects.get(pk=pk)
2. Now, query from Clinical_test

   child = Clinical_test.objects.filter(Child_detail=child_detail)

After this, you can send `child` to the context.

Comment: I am already passing child to the context but it difficult for me render data into the template,please help

Comment: So, you are facing a problem with rendering data. First, confirm you are passing info is correct, by doing print(child).